# How can i make cornerd star in html canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, canvas

I Tried make cornerd star.
But I couldn't solve that.

This is tried my source.

```js
  let canvas: HTMLCanvasElement | undefined = undefined;
    let angle = 0;
        function toRadians(degrees: number) {   
            return degrees * (Math.PI / 180);
        }
    let drawcircle = (x:number,y:number,r: number, poly: number, step: number) => {
        if(canvas) {
            const _canvas = (canvas as HTMLCanvasElement);
            const ctx = _canvas.getContext('2d');
            if(!ctx) return;
            ctx.lineWidth = 1;
            x += (r * Math.cos( toRadians(angle) ));
            y += (r * Math.sin( toRadians(angle) ));
            ctx.lineTo(x,y)
            step += 1;
            angle = poly * step;
            if(angle <= 360) requestAnimationFrame(() => drawcircle(x,y, r, poly, step));
            else {
                ctx.stroke();
            }
        }
    }
    onMount(() => {
        if(canvas) {
            drawcircle(100,100,30,30,0);
        }
    });
```

I just found this page, working in android.
http://android-er.blogspot.com/2014/05/round-corner-of-path-with.html

Comment: How is this code not meeting your expectations?

Comment: It is can't make round each corner.

Comment: Your first line is throwing an error due to invalid syntax; have you debugged with your browser's developer tools?